# I want to manipulate the state present in React class component in a helper function. I want to achieve the same in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to achieve below javascript code in typescript. I have a class component with a state which makes a call to the external helper method to modify. I need to call checkAuthentication  method present in helper.ts file and pass the context of 'this', as well as accessing the checkAuthentication method in my class component.

Class component: Home.tsx

```
import { checkAuthentication } from './routes/login/helper';

class Home extends React.Component<any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = { authenticated: null };
    this.checkAuthentication = checkAuthentication.bind(this);    
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAuthentication();
  }
  render() {
    return (      
        <></>         
    )
  }
}
```

Helper.ts file contains the checkAuthentication method which modifies the state present inside Home.tsx file

```
async function checkAuthentication() {
  const authenticated = await this.props.auth.isAuthenticated();
  if (authenticated !== this.state.authenticated) {
    if (authenticated && !this.state.userinfo) {
      const userinfo = await this.props.auth.getUser();
      this.setState({ authenticated});
    } else {
      this.setState({ authenticated });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this work in JavaScript and not in TypeScript? TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript. 

Are you saying that this doesn't work for you in TypeScript? If it works in JS then it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work out of the box (and if it works in JS then it should, unless it's a type-checking error that requires changing no-implicit-this or similar), then you could do the following:

```
function checkAuthentication(that: React.Component<any>) {
  return async function () {
    const authenticated = await that.props.auth.isAuthenticated();
    if (authenticated !== that.state.authenticated) {
      if (authenticated && !that.state.userinfo) {
        const userinfo = await that.props.auth.getUser();
        that.setState({ authenticated});
      } else {
        that.setState({ authenticated });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in your class:

```
this.checkAuthentication = checkAuthentication(this);
```